# Node Js, Async Js, Listener must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Below is the output log of the code below that, I don't know why it is throwing the error, I'm think the numbers at the end of the lines are `line number`:`char number`, I'll post some key line numbers in with the code.

> for some reason not working
>   series complete
>
> events.js:171
>       throw TypeError('listener must be a function');
>             ^ TypeError: listener must be a function
>       at TypeError ()
>       at NativeConnection.EventEmitter.once (events.js:171:11)
>       at /home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/server.js:39:24
>       at /home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:5
>   48:21
>       at /home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:2
>   24:13
>       at iterate (/home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules/async/lib/a
>   sync.js:131:13)
>       at async.eachSeries (/home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules/as
>   ync/lib/async.js:147:9)
>       at _asyncMap (/home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules/async/lib
>   /async.js:223:9)
>       at Object.mapSeries (/home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules/as
>   ync/lib/async.js:213:23)
>       at Object.async.series (/home/melman/Documents/Git/angular-test/node_modules
>   /async/lib/async.js:546:19)

```
28: var serverConfiguration = {
    init: function (){
30:       var self = this;

        async.series([
            function (callback) {
                // connect to the db
                db.connect('mongodb://localhost/piautomation');

                var dbConn = db.connection;
                dbConn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
                dbConn.once('open', callback(null));
40:         },
            function (callback) {
                console.log('Configure the db');
                self.models = require('./server/config/mongoose')(db); // setup the db with the models and schemas
                callback(null);
            },
            function (callback) {
                console.log("Start creating models");
                self.newsApi = require('./server/api/news')(self.models.News); // pass the news api the News model
                callback(null);
50:         },
            function (callback) {
                console.log("configure routes");
                require('./server/config/routes')(app, self.newsApi, clientDir, callback); // set up the routes with the model api's functions
            },
            function (callback) {
                console.log("http server created");
                var server = http.createServer(app);
                console.log("starting reload");
                reload(server, app);
60:             console.log("start server listen");
                // if we have successful db connection, allow the rest of the app to start up
                server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
                    console.log("Web server listening in %s on port %d", colors.red(process.env.NODE_ENV), app.get('port'));
                    callback(null);
                });
                console.log("for some reason not working");
                callback(null);
            }
        ], function () {
70:         console.log("series complete");
        });
    }
}.init();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing line 39 from

```
dbConn.once('open', callback(null));
```

to

```
dbConn.once('open', callback);
```

Comment: You beast :), perfect :)